# MySQL unique key seems to take only first 17characters of varchar

Tags: mysql, varchar, composite-key, unique-key, mysql-error-1062

I am trying to figure out why my database does not accept a composite unique key on MySQL v5.7.12 and using InnoDB. I found many threaads about limits on unique key sizes and problems when one reaches those but my sizes are nowhere near those limits (less than 255 chars even!). MySQL docs say the key limit is 3072bytes! http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-restrictions.html

For simplicity I provide the related field informations:

```
| ascii_name      | varchar(200)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| feature_class   | char(1)          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| feature_code    | varchar(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

I am trying to add a composite unique key

```
mysql> alter table geonames_geonames add unique (ascii_name,feature_code,feature_class);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-STM-H' for key 'ascii_name'
mysql>
```

From the error and the contents of the table I figured it uses only first 17 characters of the field. But why? If I check the table

```
mysql> select ascii_name,feature_code,feature_class from geonames_geonames where name like 'Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-%';
+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| ascii_name                    | feature_code | feature_class |
+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Dehram    | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Sabzevar  | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Sar Dasht | STM          | H             |
+-------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I also tried to give a size but result is same.

```
mysql> alter table geonames_geonames add unique (ascii_name(200),feature_code,feature_class);
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-STM-H' for key 'ascii_name'
mysql>
```

So, from where does this limit come? and is it possible to increase it? Any links to documentation which describes this limit is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: try `like 'Rudkhaneh-ye Shur%'`

Comment: omg you are right ...

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the error only prints the value and adds a dash after it, so indeed I had duplicate rows :(
I was simply looking at wrong entries...

```
mysql> select ascii_name,feature_code,feature_class from geonames_geonames where name like 'Rudkhaneh-ye Shur%';
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| ascii_name                     | feature_code | feature_class |
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | AREA         | L             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | SBED         | T             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur              | STMX         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab           | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ab Qandu     | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Barik        | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Bid          | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Chah-e Nahr  | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Chay         | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Chay         | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Chay         | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Ghamish      | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Gol Shang    | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Goleh Gah    | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Jajarm       | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Khar Turan   | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Mahur        | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Mur Dar Bala | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Naseri       | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur Shah Gheyb   | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Dehram     | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Sabzevar   | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shur-e Sar Dasht  | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurab            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurab            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurab            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurab            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurab            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurabeh          | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurabeh          | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurak            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurak            | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurani           | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurava           | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh Kand       | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh Kot        | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shureh Lang       | STMI         | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shuru             | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurug            | STM          | H             |
| Rudkhaneh-ye Shurug            | STM          | H             |
+--------------------------------+--------------+---------------+
134 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```